# Detect Zoomscale in UIWebView

Tags: iphone

My problem is that i want to detect the zoom scale of an UIWebView, i have tried searching it but did not come out with a proper answer.Any help is appreciated......

Answer (score 0):

Well although the `UIWebView` doesn't have a `zoomScale` property, `UIScrollView` does!
So we just scan it's `subView's` for the `scrollView` everything sits in and get it that way.

Here's a little (1 method) category that will allow you to get the scale by calling `[webView zoomScale]`.

**UIWebView+zoom.h file**

```
@interface UIWebView (zoom)
-(float)zoomScale;
@end
```

**UIWebView+zoom.m file**

```
@implementation UIWebView (zoom)

-(float)zoomScale{
    UIScrollView *webViewContentView;
    for (UIView *checkView in [self subviews] ) {
        if ([checkView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            webViewContentView = (UIScrollView*)checkView;
            break;
        }
    }
    return webViewContentView.zoomScale;
}

@end
```

[**UIScrollView Class Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW41)

[**UIWebView's View Hierarchy**](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/02/10/exploring-iphone-view-hierarchies/) (Don't rely on it though, always scan the `webView` to avoid code breaking when apple makes changes to `iOS`)

**NOTE: This code should work but has been written in the reply box so hasn't been tested.**

Comment: Problem is that this will always return 1.0 except when the user is actually in the act of zooming in or out. So it's a value that really only gives the ratio of the current active zoom scale to the zoom scale that existed when the user first started the zoom.