# iOS UIwebview Zoom scale detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebview` where i have `SWIPE` RIGHT and LEFT gesture to move to next pages in `UIwebview`. When the `webview` is zoomed **i don't want to allow SWIPE GESTURE**. I have done this in `ViewdidLoad`.

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
webView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 106,966,500);
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I'm also adding Gesture in ViewdidLoad:

```
//Swipe Gesture for Webview
    swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction)];
    swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction)];

    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    swipeRight.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.delegate = self;
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

When zooming is done the GESTURE should not happen. How can i solve this?

Comment: if zooming is done set ' [webView removeGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];' and ' [webView removeGestureRecognizer: swipeRight];'

Comment: how can i detect zooming is done..

Comment: refer this [http://pastebin.com/BH0K2A9Q](http://pastebin.com/BH0K2A9Q)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859513/detect-zoomscale-in-uiwebview

Comment: thanks Ashini and Spynet..